# Is $\frac{\partial X}{\partial I_{rs}}=x_{rs}$ right?Proof of $\frac{\partial y_{mn}}{\partial X}=\mathbf A^T \mathbf I_{mn} \mathbf B^T$

Tags: matrices, derivatives

The book said that $\mathbf X$ is a real matrix,and $\frac{\partial\mathbf X}{\partial x_{rs}}=\mathbf I_{rs}$.Can i think as because $\frac{\partial\mathbf X}{\partial \mathbf I_{rs}}=x_{rs}$,so $\frac{\partial\mathbf X}{\partial x_{rs}}=\mathbf I_{rs}$ ?

I mean ,is  $\frac{\partial\mathbf X}{\partial \mathbf I_{rs}}=x_{rs}$ right?Because i think this formula$,\frac{\partial\mathbf X}{\partial \mathbf I_{rs}}=x_{rs}$, is easier to explain.

Explaination:If you want to get an element,which is at the $r$ row and $s$ clomn , in the $\mathbf X$ matrix ,then derivative the $\mathbf I_{rs}$ so that you can extract the $x_{rs}$ from $\mathbf X$ matrix

The another question is according to $\frac{\partial\mathbf X}{\partial x_{rs}}=\mathbf I_{rs}$,and $\mathbf Y =\mathbf A \mathbf X \mathbf B$,then $\frac{\partial\mathbf Y}{\partial x_{rs}}=\mathbf A \mathbf I_{rs} \mathbf B$ if only if $\frac{\partial y_{mn}}{\partial X}=\mathbf A^T \mathbf I_{mn} \mathbf B^T$.

I can understand why is $\frac{\partial\mathbf Y}{\partial x_{rs}}=\mathbf A \mathbf I_{rs} \mathbf B$,but i can't understans why is $\frac{\partial y_{mn}}{\partial \mathbf X}=\mathbf A^T \mathbf I_{mn} \mathbf B^T$,can anyone explain this to me?

Comment: The notation $\frac{\partial\mathbf X}{\partial \mathbf I_{rs}}=x_{rs}$ looks meaningless to me. For one thing, you derivate with respect a _variable_  , always, and  $\mathbf I_{rs}$ is not a variable. Further, It makes sense to write the derivative of a matrix with respect a scalar variable (we derivate each element of the matrix with respect that variable, and write each result as a matrix elemente: we get a matrix). But it  does not make sense to derivate a matrix with respect another matrix (well, it could make sense, but it would give a 4D matrix or something like that . never a scalar).

Comment: so $\frac{\partial \mathbf X}{\partial \mathbf I_{rs}}=x_{rs}$ is wrong?$I_{rs} $ is a identity matrix.

Comment: Yes, it's wrong, or more than than, meaningless. I wrote a detailed comment to explain you why

Comment: I just answered a [similar question](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3018708/357854)  and seeing this question, I suspect there is a textbook out there that using $I_{mn}$ to denote the single-entry matrix. It's a poor notation, since $I$ is usually used to denote the identity matrix.