# why is $\frac{\partial y_{mn}}{\partial \mathbf X}= \mathbf B \mathbf I_{mn}^T\mathbf A$

Tags: matrices, derivatives

I have find some reason why $\frac{\partial y_{mn}}{\partial \mathbf X}= \mathbf B  \mathbf I_{mn}^T\mathbf A$ when $\mathbf Y=\mathbf A \mathbf X^T \mathbf B$ in some books,but i can't still understand why,can anyone teach me how to calculate it in detail?

$\mathbf A$ is $m*k$ matrix,$\mathbf B$ is $i*n$ matrix,$\mathbf X$ is $i*k$ matrix

Comment: What are the orders of $A,B,X$?

Comment: @MostafaAyaz i have edited the question

Comment: One more thing: how do you define $X^TB$ when $X$ is $k\times i$ and $B$ is $i\times n$? Shouldn't it be $XB$?

Comment: sry,terrible mistake

Comment: @MostafaAyaz i improved it

Comment: That's ok......

Comment: Are the $m$ and $n$ mentioned as orders of matrices $A,B$ different with those as indices in $$y_{mn}?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting with
$$\eqalign{
Y &= AX^TB \cr
}$$
Take the Frobenius product with the single-entry matrix to isolate the $(m,n)$ element.
$$\eqalign{
y_{mn} &= E_{mn}:Y \cr
 &= E_{mn}:AX^TB \cr
 &= E_{mn}^T:B^TXA^T \cr
 &= BE_{mn}^TA:X \cr
}$$
Now find the differential and gradient of this element wrt $X$
$$\eqalign{
dy_{mn} &= BE_{mn}^TA:dX \cr
\frac{\partial y_{mn}}{\partial X} &= BE^T_{mn}A \cr
}$$
There is no standard notation for the single-entry matrix. I use the letter ${\mathbf E}$ others use ${\mathbf J}$, but ${\mathbf I}$ is a confusing choice since it usually denotes the identity matrix.

**NB:**  The Frobenius product is just a convenient way to write the trace function 
$$A:B = {\rm Tr}(A^TB)$$

Comment: so in this calculation,$BB^T=I$?

Comment: Why would you think that? This calculation is agnostic about the properties of the $(A,B,X)$ matrices other than they must have compatible dimensions to allow the product $AX^TB$.

Comment: because here  $E_{mn}^T:B^TXA^T = BE_{mn}^TA:X $

Comment: You can prove this using the properties of the trace $$\eqalign{
E^T:B^TXA^T
&={\rm Tr}(EB^TXA^T)\cr
&={\rm Tr}(A^TEB^TX)\cr
&={\rm Tr}\big((BE^TA)^TX\big)\cr
&=BE^TA:X
}$$